# How to change the Bodies and sprites on the fly? Box2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I'm starting to develop now and came across a problem: I have a body that is a rock and when it initiate contact with another body (which would be a character), would like to replace that body for several pieces of the same body to simulate a fissure, maintaining the same speed that the body had. Is that possible? How should I proceed?

Some code would be amazing!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After years of programming I have come to one major realization. NOTHING (in regards to programming) is impossible except for expecting someone else to write your code completely for you.

With that in mind I would suggest doing some research into how you might accomplish this. Simply asking someone for code to do something you want to do isn't going to solicit much help from anyone. You could try creating new sprites/bodies at the moment of impact and applying the same speed of the previous object effectively replacing the original sprite.

Comment: Yes, my intention here is not that other people write the code for me, as I said above, I am new on it and am trying to learn. This is not my only source of information, it is not as if I were sitting waiting for people to create codes for me. I'm reading some books and trying new things on various websites, and I'm doing my own tests as well.

Thank you for the tips!

Comment: Well you didnt really say you were new at it you said you are starting to develop now. I took that as you are starting to develop this game now, not that you have never worked in development at all before. As I said peviously this is what I would do:

You could try creating new sprites/bodies at the moment of impact and applying the same speed of the previous object effectively replacing the original sprite.

Unless there is some type of tool available to do it for you. There isnt any that I know of but its very possible there is. I would check around github and see if you can find something